# rails5の開発環境用データについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsで開発環境用のデータをどのように導入しますか？
開発に途中から入る人とかいた場合、ある程度データがないと開発しづらいと思い、初期データを作っておいて、サービスを触れるような状態にしたいと考えております。
方法としてdev用のseedを用意するということを思いついたのですが、何か他にいい方法あれば教えてください。
環境はrails5.0.1、mysqlになります。

Comment: seedではなにか困ることがあるのでしょうか？なぜ他の方法を求めているのかわかればそれに応じた適切な回答が得られる可能性がありますが、理由がわからないと回答が得られなかったり、雑多な回答の羅列しか得られないことになります

Comment: seedで実装することも考えたのですが、他の方法もあれば知りたかったので質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seedと同じような機能でseed_fuというgemがあります。
seedだと1ファイルが大きくなってしまうので私はいつもseed_fuを使っています。

https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu

こんな感じでmodelごとにファイルを管理しています。

https://github.com/tackeyy/blog/tree/master/db/fixtures/development

Answer (score 0):

するとすれば、DBを丸ごとエクスポート、リストアでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
そうなると、やはりseedで作成するのがベストのように感じるのでseedを用いて実装することにします。